# Do I need to show proof I will be leaving UK when I enter (as an EU citizen)?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, study, eu-citizens, proof-of-onward-travel

I will be studying abroad in Edinburgh in the fall and will be using my Dutch passport the whole time I am there, as EU citizens don't need visas to study in the UK (I have dual citizenship for the US and Netherlands). After the semester I will be traveling around Europe for a couple weeks and then flying back to the US from Amsterdam. I have my flight back to the US booked but do not have any sort of flight out of the UK booked (as I do not know when my finals will end). My question is will this be a big deal at customs, or is my flight out of Amsterdam proof enough that I won't be in the UK for longer than allowed?

Comment: To be clear, you mean "immigration", *not* customs. They are often confused, but are not the same thing.

Comment: If you hold an electronic passport, then as an EU citizen you may not even need to speak to an actual person at immigration, you can just go through the automated gate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPassport_gates

Comment: @AE Personal anecdote: I have never known those to actually work, and not for lack of trying.

Comment: @Lilienthal Worked for me last time I came into the UK - had to take my glasses off.

Comment: Worked for me with my glasses

Comment: @AndrewFerrier so is customs just declaring things you have if, or can they also ask you questions about the purpose of your visit and such?

Comment: There is no Fall in the UK, just Autumn :)

Comment: @JesseBaljon they might ask you those questions, if they stopped you. But immigration is the normal place where your passport is checked and questions about your visit are asked. It does vary country to country, but in most, they are separate steps.

Comment: Immigtation is checking you, and your right/authorisation to enter the country. Customs is checking goods, and if the appropriate taxes are paid.

Comment: "longer than allowed": as an EU citizen, you are allowed to stay as long as you want.  They can't kick you out unless you commit serious crime, or, in some cases, go on the dole, or, possibly, after they leave the EU.

Answer (score 8):

As an EU citizen, you don't have any time limit on remaining in the UK necessarily, [under EU freedom of movement rules.](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=457) Now freedom of movement technically applies only to workers, but practically it means that you can enter the "EU" line in the passport queue, and nobody will bother asking you any questions. It also means that you could remain once your study had finished, simply by looking for a job ( you could register at the jobcentre to prove this if really needed)

The [specific rules for students](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/student/rights-conditions/index_en.htm) depends a little on how long you will be staaying for.

> ## Staying abroad for up to 3 months
>
> As an EU national, you have the right to study in another EU country. If you stay there for less than 3 months, all you will need is a valid identity card or passport.
>
> ## Staying abroad for more than 3 months
>
> You have the right to live in any EU country for the duration of your studies if you:
>
> - are enrolled in an approved educational establishment
> - have sufficient income (from any source) to live without needing income support
> - have comprehensive health insurance cover there.
>
> National authorities may not require your income to be above the level that would qualify you for basic income support.
>
> You could lose your right to stay in the country if you finish your studies and cannot prove you are in work or still have sufficient resources to support yourself.

Relaxed provides a link to [this overview of what freedom of movement means](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-does-european-union-freedom-of-movement-mean-and-how-much-can-individual/4965#4965). For you, it means you can just saunter in pretty casual and go to your course.

Comment: (+1) Not only workers now. Workers, students and economically non-active persons who do note create a burden on the host state, and members of their family.

Comment: Was just going off the text in the first link - which specifically says that freedom of movement means that you can:
    "look for a job in another EU country   
    work there without needing a work permit
    reside there for that purpose
    stay there even after employment has finished
    enjoy equal treatment with nationals in access to employment, working conditions and all other social and tax advantages". Of course, it is entirely possible that the EU's own website is out of date.

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of definition. That's the classical article 45 freedom of movement for workers, which exists since the beginning. Usually “freedom of movement” also covers article 21. But it's true the phrase does not appear in there, only “right to move and reside freely” (added with the Maastricht treaty). See also http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-does-european-union-freedom-of-movement-mean-and-how-much-can-individual/4965#4965

Answer (score 5):

As @CMaster explained, you have a right to stay for as long as you like in the UK and you're not required to prove you will leave as there are many ways for you to make sure you are entitled to a longer stay (like finding a job…). Unlike non-EU nationals, you are also entitled to change your mind about this at any time, there is no requirement for you to obtain a specific visa in advance depending on the purpose of your stay. If you stay longer than three months, you could in principle be asked then, but only then, to show that you fulfil some conditions (i.e. that you are either working, studying, have sufficient resources or live with an EU citizen who does).

In principle, you therefore *should not* be asked any question. It's not only that border guards don't bother but they are not supposed to assess anything apart from the genuineness of your ID and citizenship and possibly that you do not present a threat to national security. Your plans and their credibility are immaterial and don't need to be discussed like they are for third-country nationals (including US citizens).

In practice, I frequently go to the UK on my ID card from another EU country and I never had to answer any question whatsoever. You line up in front of the EU/EEA citizen booth, along with British people, some border guard looks at your ID, scans it, and looks at your face, maybe grumbles a few words and you are on your way (that's for immigration, customs is later, incidentally). Nobody will want to see your ticket or ask where you are going or what you want to do. A passport isn't needed either, a Dutch ID card would be enough (but a passport is completely fine too of course).

Comment: The Schengen rules don't require an online passport / ID card check, so Schengen guards can (and often do) just look at the passport then let you in. UK rules require a scan of EU passport and ID cards, which takes longer.

Comment: And if you go by ferry from the UK to continental Europe they might not even check the ID cards. I've had cases (with a car) where they checked our German IDs and some where they only made a comment about Germany being great at football and waved us on without even taking our IDs, just because of the German plates on the car.

Answer (score 2):

The only bureaucratic difficulty I encountered when I moved from Germany to the UK to work there was that after a few weeks in my new job I got a form in which I was supposed to fill in the dates of every single previous stay in the UK. I had been there before, but that had been many years ago and obviously I didn't remember precise dates. I would expect that giving approximations to such a stupid and pointless question does not have any consequences, though.

The only other issue you might have is with health insurance. You will probably be covered (for free!) by NHS even when moving from the US to the UK to study there, but I am not sure and you should check this. In any case I would expect that once your studies are over and you only stay in the UK for a few weeks for fun you will technically not be covered by NHS. And NHS is certainly not responsible for you while traveling elsewhere in Europe. So if you get diagnosed with something serious during that time, or have a bad accident, you might be in serious trouble if you don't get some other form of health insurance.

One issue you might run into after your stay: In some cases a health insurer may require proof that you were covered by health insurance previously. If you lived in the UK there isn't really anything to prove because (almost, see above) everyone is automatically covered by NHS. As a consequence, if a health insurer insists on proof, as happened in the case of my daughter, it's not at all clear what to do. If you think this might happen to you, be sure to get some form of proof before you leave the country. When I tried this from Germany, I failed. In the UK the process usually involves calling special phone numbers that are not easily accessible from outside the country, and of course it's also harder to get information from abroad.